# How to create a collection and insert values in a table with the collection?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

Hey I am creating a database to store some information about a sport club, where I have trainers and athletes, but when I am trying to insert trainers(entrenadors) to the table that errors appears:

[image]

The code that I have is this one:

1. Creation of the person type (t_persona) who inherit the types of coach and athletes. We must create a function that returns all the data

`CREATE OR REPLACE type t_persona as object(
 nom VARCHAR2(20),
 cognom VARCHAR2(20),
 dataNaix DATE,
 MEMBER PROCEDURE mostrar
) NOT FINAL;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE type body t_persona AS
 MEMBER PROCEDURE mostrar IS
 BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Nom: ' || nom || 'Cognom: ' || cognom || 'DataNaix: ' || dataNaix);
 END;
END;
/`

2.Creation of the curs type (t_curs).

`CREATE OR REPLACE type t_curs as object(
 nom VARCHAR2(50),
 hores NUMBER(10),
 lloc VARCHAR2(50),
 dia DATE
);`

3.Creation of the collection of courses (t_cursos) of type t_curs.

`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_cursos AS varray(20) of t_curs;`

4.Creation of the coach type (t_entrenandor), must be inherited from type t_persona. This must have a function that returns all the data reusing the function of t_persona.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type t_entrenador under t_persona(
   telefon VARCHAR2(9),
   cursos t_cursos,
OVERRIDING MEMBER PROCEDURE mostrar);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE type body t_entrenador as
OVERRIDING MEMBER PROCEDURE  mostrar is
 BEGIN
   (self as t_persona).mostrar;
    dbms_output.put_line('Telefon: ' || telefon || 'Cursos : ' || cursos);
  END;
END;
```

5.Create table entrenadors that with contain entrenadors.

```
CREATE TABLE entrenadors of t_entrenador
```

6. Insert into table entrenadors two entrena

`INSERT INTO entrenadors VALUES('Daniel', 'Rovira', to_date('12/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'), '65555222', t_cursos('spinning', 1, 'España', to_date('12/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY')));`

In that number 6 is where the error occurs, can someone help me finding what is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Your `t_entrenador` type body will not compile. The reference to `cursos` is invalid here: `dbms_output.put_line('Telefon: ' || telefon || 'Cursos : ' || cursos);` . It's a table and DBMS_OUTPUT cannot render it. You need to reference an attribute of the table, say `cursos.count()`.

Comment: I see i will fixe that! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t_entrenador.cursos` has datatype of `t_cursos` which is a table of `t_curs`. To instantiate the table you need to pass **instances of `t_curs`**.

```
INSERT INTO entrenadors 
VALUES('Daniel', 'Rovira', to_date('12/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'), '65555222',
        t_cursos(t_curs('spinning', 1, 'España', to_date('12/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))
   )
  );
```